# Why FCM does not work in the region different than its registered region?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate FCM in my android app. Notifications are sent perfectly if I register my app with country as India (where notification are being tested). But notifications are not sent if the app is registered in US and I am testing it from a phone in India. Is there any kind of restriction in FCM regarding region?

Comment: Hi. Are you sending the notifications from your own App server or from the Notifications Console? Have you tried both? Is the behavior the same? AFAIK, there is *no* geo restrictions for FCM.

Comment: I am sending notifications from firebase console. First, I registered my app in US region and I was testing on the phone which was in India, at that time I did not get notifications. Then I registered my app in India region, and I started getting notification on my mobile which was in India.

Comment: There is no difference for FCM in which region you registered your app.
Maybe there was a problem in the first configuration.

Answer (score 0):

FCM makes no difference based on the region where you registered your app.

It's possible that there was some other problem with your first configuration, or maybe FCM was having some issues when you tried it.